# How to create join query from different ADO connection

Tags: delphi, ado, foxpro, dbase

I want to create join query from result adoquery.
And adoquery connect into different ADOConnection.

- ADOQuery1 -> ADOConnection1 -> MS Access (MS Jet Driver)
- ADOQuery2 or ADOTable -> ADOConnection2 -> Microsoft Visual Foxpro

I want to create join query in ADOQuery3 and connect to ADOConnection1 but
query from resultset ADOQuery1 and ADOQuery2.

ADOQuery3 -> ADOQuery1 + ADOQuery2.

But

I can not use link table (link microsoft visual foxpro table) in MS Access because it can not use share mode on dbase (microsoft visual foxpro table).

Comment: I don't think this is possible with ADO. To make it work you'll need an SQL engine in your client, either installed on the local machine or built in to your application. Then import the two result sets to that SQL engine and query against them. There are a range of products that can do that - NexusDB, for example.

Comment: Have a look at http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE2/en/Establishing_Master-detail_Relationships_Using_Parameters

Comment: And also have a look at http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Data.Win.ADODB.TADOTable.MasterSource

Comment: Thank for advice. But I want to join all record on adoqery1 and adoquery2. If i use master detail concept. It is filter some record to show me.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to join between two tables located in different access databases like this:

```
adq.SQL.Add('select * from');
adq.SQL.Add('(c:\DB1.MDB.TABLE1)');
adq.SQL.Add('left outer join');
adq.SQL.Add('(c:\DB2.mdb.TABLE2)');
adq.SQL.Add('on (TABLE1.TABLE2_ID = TABLE2.ID)');
adq.SQL.Add('where ');
// add some restrictions
```

I know it does not immediately solve your problem, I just thought I'd should point this out, maybe it can help you to find a solution. (I don't currently have the time to do my own research.)